# How to call a function of a class from a `for` loop in python

Tags: python, loops, oop

I have a list which contains functions of a class. I want to iterate through that list and call the function.

I have created an object for the class as such:

```
a=class1()
list_functions=['add("pavan",9)', 'add("pavan2",9:10)', 
'add("pavan3",9:30)', 'add("pavan4",9:40)', '']
```

My for loop will be:

```
for i in  range(len(list_functions)):
    a.[list_functions[i]]
```

But this gives me an error. Please help me understand.

Comment: can you please add error to the question?

Comment: `a.[` this will not work. How does the class look and what is the error?

Comment: Please give your code in a readable format, and provide us with the traceback.

Comment: _have a list which contains functions of a class_ - no, what you have is list of strings. Moreover, if you really want to treat this strings as a code to execute, you CANNOT do that, since this strings are invalid in Python syntax. Please update your question with clear problem statement, clear expected behaviour and exact error you're encountering right now.

Answer (score -1):

The following might be the kind of thing you're looking for:

```
funcs = [(lambda x: x.add('pavan', 9)), (lambda x: x.add('pavan2', slice(9, 10)))]
for f in funcs:
    f(a)
```

It's not a good idea to put code in strings for calling later, although it is possible. Lambdas allow you store little bits of functionality like this.